# Reconocer secuencia de dígitos en una imagen

Tags: python, tensorflow, redes-neuronales, inteligencia-artificial, keras

estoy aprendiendo a programar redes neuronales y demás, y me gustaría saber como puedo sacar los números que hay en una imagen, por ejemplo si paso una imagen que tiene escrito 123, sacar con mi modelo que hay escritos 123, he intentado usar pytesseract no es muy preciso, y me gustaría hacerlo con una red neuronal, mi código actual es bastante sencillo, reconoce los dígitos del conjunto de datos mnist tal que así:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

print('train_images.shape:', train_images.shape)
print('test_images.shape:', test_images.shape)
plt.imshow(train_images[0])

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1))
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))

train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)
 

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (28, 28, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'sgd', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size = 100, epochs = 5, verbose = 1)

test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

print('Test accuracy:', test_accuracy)
```

pero necesitaría saber como puedo hacer para pasarle una imagen con una secuencia de dígitos, y que me reconozca los dígitos en cuestión, ¿Alguien sabe como podría hacerlo? Muchas gracias.

Comment: No sé exactamente qué estás buscando, pero ¿has oído hablar del [reconocimiento óptico de caracteres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition#Pre-processing) ? Si no es así, probablemente esto sea algo de lo que debas investigar.

Comment: si, es lo que estoy usando ahora mismo, pero no logro hacer que sea muy preciso

Answer (score 1):

Te platico, hice justamente un proyecto final en una materia de computer vision.
Hay tres formas de hacerlo:

1. Ventanas moviles.
2. Analisis de componentes conectados.
3. Dentro de la misma red neuronal.

La mas facil e intuitiva es la de ventanas moviles la cual es:

1. Entrenas una red neuronal con digitos y no digitos (como la que tienes en tu pregunta y con 11 clases)
2. En la imagen, pasas una ventana movil y recortas cuadras de la imagen de diferentes tamaños. Estos recortes los pasas a la red neuronal para que los clasifique. (se llama ventana movil porque iniciales desde esquina superior izquierda hasta la esquina inferior derecha, y mueves la ventana de izquierda a derecha y bajas un renglon a la vez ya que termines de pasar a lo largo).
3. Tienes que tomar varios tamaños de ventanas para poder cubrir los posibles candidatos.
4. Como vas a tener varios candidatos en la misma seccion de espacio, sas un algoritmo llamado non-maximum-supression que te ayuda a determinar el espacio.
   Pros: Intuitivo y facil de implementar.
   Cons: Muy tardado

La opcion de la red neuronal es aun mucho mas dificil de implementar por lo que seguramente solo tendras que utilizar una libreria ya hecha que implementen esos algoritmos como YOLO, SSD, etc.
Pros: Solo usas la libreria
Cons: Tunear el entrenamiento para todo pipeline.

La opciond de componentes conectados es la que yo use en mi trabajo final. Es parecida a la ventanas moviles respecto a que se entrena una red que clasifique digitos y no digitos, pero en vez de sacar espacios candidatos con ventanas moviles, se hace por un procesamiento de imagen. Yo use OpenCV python y ahi hay un algoritmo que se llama Maximally Strable Extremal Regions (MSER) que tienes que tunear para poder aislar los digitos (te recomiendo leer blogs o papers al respecto). Se clasifica cada recorte e igual manera le aplicas el non maximum supression y ya tendras clasificados los recortes.
Pros: Aislar el entrenamiento de la red a solo clasificacion (te recomiendo usar transfer learning)
Cons: Tienes que tunear el algoritmo de MSER y experimentar en OpenCV.

No es perfecto y necesitar tunearlo igualmente pero es una muy buena aproximacion a tener algo decente.
Aqui te pongo unos resultados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero necesitaría usar pytesseract o algo por el estilo pero no encuentro cómo hacer que solo detecte números

Comment: Yo no he usado pytesseract pero a lo que veo te detecta caracteres y numeros. Suponiendo que te da los cortes importantes, me imagino que directamente te puede dar los recuadros donde estan nada mas los numeros... en caso que no (que se me haria muy raro) podrias entrenar un clasificador con 11 clases (0-9 y no numeros) para hacer la distincion.

Comment: pero como podría saber la secuencia exacta? Por ejemplo, si detecto un ractángulo con 8 números, y saco uno a uno, se detectarían en orden o podría detectar primero el segundo número porque esta mas claro o cosas por el estilo? Muchas gracias

Comment: Usando pytesseract no lo se. En el metodo que te explique te da recortes de numeros por separado (te da el recorte y la posicion), y ese ya lo metes a tu red. Entonces con la clasificacion y la posicion, ya sabes el numero y la orden de aparicion.

Answer (score 0):

El objetivo principal es el reconocimiento de texto, sin embargo, el código que publicas es para la tarea de clasificación. Entonces necesitaras usar un enfoque diferente para eso. Mencionaste que vas a dar el modelo `123` y recibir `123`. Pero no se puede hacer eso solo con redes convolucionales. Las imágenes con texto son secuenciales, por lo que debe utilizar **CRNN** (Convolutional-Recurrent-Neural-Networks), **LSTM** (Long-Short-Term-Memory), **BiLSTM** (Bidirectional-LSTM). En la mayoría de los artículos de investigación, se utilizan redes convolucionales solo para la etapa de extracción de características. Para la etapa de predicción utilizaron unidades recurrentes, como celdas LSTM o RNN.

Como recomendación podrías usar LSTM o RCNN que tendría sentido. En el caso de los valores aleatorios, he descubierto que una CNN de dos o tres capas que luego desciende a través de dos redes densas paralelas hace un excelente trabajo identificando caracteres aleatorios estilo **CAPTCHA**. Una ruta es la principal responsable de identificar los cuadros delimitadores, la otra es determinar qué caracteres están presentes.

Hay muchas otras formas de solucionar este problema. Podría hacer bien en investigar la resolución de **CAPTCHA** a través de redes neuronales. Más específicamente, **CAPTCHA** basados ​​en texto. Si su tarea realmente es solo OCR, investigue OCR a través de redes neuronales. La técnica que describo aquí funcionará pero resultará engorrosa para una página de texto. En ese caso, una **CNN** de ventana deslizante junto con una capa densa y un **LSTM** tiene más sentido, ya que tratará con secuencias predecibles de caracteres.